# Kendo UI Grid update only changed cell/column

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

When performing an update on the grid it sends all column data.

I have something where updates are performed after the cell is closed:

```
change: function (e) {
        if (e.action == "itemchange") {
            this.sync();
        }
    }
```

Instead of sending all the data for every column, how can I get it to only send the data that was changed?

Answer (score 0):

You can check for Isdirty flag.When cell data is modified the respective model item is marked as Isdirty=true.

```
var data = grid.dataSource.data();
var dirty = $.grep(data, function(item) {
return item.dirty
});
// Dirty array contains those elements modified
console.log("dirty", dirty);
```

Here I'm doing for the entire grid data.You can do the same for single row.

Comment: Question is not about how to mark a model as edited, but about how to pass not all the fields(cells), but only specific one. Because the Model on UI is not the same entities in database. Making them equal and passing entities from ORM  to UI without Entity to Model mapping  (or  known as a Model in MVC) is a monkey code.